# How can i get NON contains data from list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq

I have "Contains" method but I need a "Not Contains" method. Any suggestions?

```
var ResultsOfMPD = (from m in engMpdMultiSelect
                    where engMpdMultiItems.Select(o => o.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO).
                    Contains(m.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO)
                    select m);
```

is there any method like that?

```
var ResultsOfMPD = (from m in engMpdMultiSelect
                    where engMpdMultiItems.Select(o => o.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO).
                    NOTContains(m.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO)
                    select m);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `!` operator, like this:

```
var ResultsOfMPD = from m in engMpdMultiSelect
                   where !engMpdMultiItems.Select(o => o.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO).
                   Contains(m.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO)
                   select m;
```

By the way, you don't need the `Select()` call.
Instead, you can write

```
var ResultsOfMPD = from m in engMpdMultiSelect
                   where !engMpdMultiItems.Any(o => o.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO == m.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO)
                   select m;
```

Or, equivalently,

```
var ResultsOfMPD = from m in engMpdMultiSelect
                   where engMpdMultiItems.All(o => o.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO != m.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO)
                   select m;
```

Comment: how can i use? !contains(. . . .

Comment: If Foo() returns boolean, !Foo() returns the opposite, therefore if engMpdMultiItems.Select().Contains() returns boolean, !engMpdMultiItems.Select().Contains() returns the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ResultsOfMPD = from m in engMpdMultiSelect
                   where engMpdMultiItems.All(x => x.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO != m.ENG_MPD_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO)
                   select m;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Except method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)?

FYI - In set theory this is called a Relative Complement.  That is, given two sets A and B, the set of all elements which are in B but not in A is referred to as the relative complement of set A with respect to set B.  But not contains or except works too.